# Disable outgoing mail for an account?

Tags: macos, mail.app

I have an account that I want to receive but never send email from in Mail.app. Is there a simple way to disable this one account?

I'm running Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option within the preferences of Mail.app.

Go to the "Accounts" tab, and select the email account, and under **Account Information**, you can set the outgoing mail server to **None**.

You must also enable **Use only this server**.

When sending a message from that account, you will now get a message asking you to choose a different outgoing mail server, with the option of cancelling the send.

Comment: I can confirm that what you suggested works in Mountain Lion.

Comment: This doesn't actually do anything; you can still send messages without a prompt. It just picks one of the other servers to send with.

Comment: Setting **Use only this server** causes a prompt to appear.